# SQL server - Get newest record of join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

After reading Stackoverflow for quite some time, today it's my turn to ask a question!

**Table structure**
It's related to a query to a SQL server 2005 database. I have the following table structure:

*components*

- id

*downloads*

- id
- componentid (FK to components#id)
- downloaddate

*imports*

- id
- downloadid (FK to downloads#id)
- status

**What I want to get**
I am trying to get the status of the latest download for each component.

**Where I am so far**
I have started writing this query, but my join is not working quite well:

```
SELECT c.id  
FROM components as c  
JOIN (    
  SELECT componentid, MAX(downloaddate) as downloaddate, id  
  FROM downloads  
  GROUP BY componentid, id   
) d ON d.componentid = c.id  
-- JOIN on imports here...
```

My problem is that the query used for the join is not correct. Because I need to select the id for the join, I added it in the group by clause and I now get multiple records for each componentid, instead of the latest one.

Here is what I get if I execute the query in the join on its own.

```
componentid downloaddate            id

8882    2011-01-15 06:00:09.773 595862
8882    2011-01-16 06:00:09.847 598422
8882    2011-01-17 06:00:09.940 600971
8951    2010-11-15 03:00:22.550 450221
8951    2010-11-16 03:00:21.730 452431
8951    2010-11-17 03:00:21.920 454668
8961    2011-01-17 02:00:33.077 600532
8961    2011-01-17 02:00:59.070 600536
8983    2008-07-17 11:59:53.780 122
9005    2009-09-01 04:00:38.320 48918
9005    2009-09-02 04:00:36.260 49280
```

Instead, I need something like this:

```
componentid downloaddate            id

8882    2011-01-17 06:00:09.940 600971
8951    2010-11-17 03:00:21.920 454668
8961    2011-01-17 02:00:59.070 600536
8983    2008-07-17 11:59:53.780 122
9005    2009-09-02 04:00:36.260 49280
```

Does anyone know how I should write my join to achieve the expected result?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can 1 `download` be associated with multiple `imports`? If so which status value do you need?

Comment: Yes, one download has multiple imports. I want to get the status of the latest import (they have dates as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot correlate the JOIN operator. Use APPLY instead:

```
SELECT c.id , d.downloaddate
FROM components as c  
APPLY (    
  SELECT componentid, MAX(downloaddate) as downloaddate  
  FROM downloads  
  WHERE componentid = c.id
) as d;
```

Actually you could use a JOIN too (since the inner query is no correlated actually), but don't group by id, just group by componentid:

```
SELECT c.id , d.downloaddate
FROM components as c  
JOIN (    
  SELECT componentid, MAX(downloaddate) as downloaddate  
  FROM downloads  
  GROUP BY componentid 
) as d ON c.id = d.componentid;
```

*Updated*:

```
SELECT *
FROM components as c  
APPLY (    
  SELECT TOP(1) componentid, downloaddate, id as downloadid
  FROM downloads  
  WHERE componentid = c.id
  ORDER BY downloaddate DESC
) as d
JOIN imports i on i.id = d.downloadid;
```

Comment: Can't he just move the GROUP BY out of the JOIN ? and do a simple join on the downloads table (no inner query)?

Comment: Thanks Remus, can you please explain how I could join on the imports table as well? My problem is that I have to return the id of the download's table to join it on imports. Thanks!

Comment: @Zunanadi: You need to group by componentid to use the function MAX(downloaddate)
@Remus: I am sorry, but I cannot get any of your solutions to solve my final problem, as they do not allow me to return the id of downloads (as I still have to group by componentid)

Comment: @user578646 - You can use `ROW_NUMBER` as in Eric's answer or stick with `APPLY` but use `TOP (1)` instead of `MAX`

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've also got it working with apply and top(1). Which is best in terms of performance?

Comment: @user578646 RE: Performance I think it depends upon what indexes you have and the average number of downloads per component. If this number is high then `cross apply` and individual seeks may perform better if there are relatively few then `row_number` may perform better.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for you reply. I have implemented both, and the cross apply performs better indeed as my data set is quite large.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably solve this using the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
SELECT componentid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY componentid ORDER BY downloaddate DESC) as rowno
FROM downloads  
WHERE rowno = 1
```

Comment: Your solution works. I added ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY componentid ORDER BY downloaddate DESC) as rowno in my sub query for the join. In addition, I put rowno=1 in the condition of my join and it did the trick. Thank you Eric!

Comment: @user - You might be able to eliminate the sub query entirely. ROW_NUMBER doesn't require a group by - so you can join in other tables as well if you want.

Comment: Thanks Eric for teaching me something. I'll use cross apply this time however, as it seems to work better for that particular problem.